# load via ajax, compare content, animate changes

Tags: jquery, ajax, e-commerce

I'm trying to make our basket add/remove items with Ajax. This is fairly straight forward.

I plan to return the entire basket container on each AJAX request. Thus making sure i have all the correct discounts given etc. etc.

Is there an easy way to compare the old basket container with the new one, and then animate changes? Ie. after a remove line item, then the new content will be missing a div compared to the old, then i want to animate that line item disappearing.

I got the animation stuff nailed, so my question is more on a way to compare the 2 containers.
And act upon the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the text of each line is unique, you can compare the text of each line with [jquery text method.](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and use `$(youReceivedData).text()` for example. Or you can get the html() of your basket and compare it with the html returned by you Ajax query. Look at [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in jQuery.

What you can do is to animate your stuff (like fadeOut the removed line and make your ajax in the same time, then when animation is finish, you change html by the returned html from your ajax request.

Usually, when I'm doing add in jQuery, I just grab one line : for example, when someone post a comment, I send the form to the controller, then I proccess the add comment, generate html code for the new comment and return it. So the comment row is a single element and html is always the same.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that i could compare with html(), i think that 's what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add some metadata to your basket divs when you render them. Somekind of id to differentiate the items from each other. You might already have this though. Like so:

```
<div data-cartitem="1">Book</div>
<div data-cartitem="2">Bread</div>
<div data-cartitem="3">Soda</div>
```

Then when you return the ajax-calls response, I suggest using [JSON](http://json.org/) dataformat because it's easy to use with javascript/jquery. After your ajax call is finished, simply run a little script (I use jquery here) to hide (or remove) the cartitems that are no longer in the cart. Here is an example where the "newcart"-variable is a json-object array (returned by ajax) that contains the current cartitems. It then hides the divs that are not in this json-array:

```
$("div").filter(function () {
    var $div = $(this);
    return $(newcart).filter(function () {                
        return (this.cartitem == $div.data("cartitem"));
    }).size() === 0;
}).fadeOut("slow");
```

Check out the whole example in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SyUAt/1/) to get the point.

Comment: I agree that JSON would be the way to go if each line item was uniform. But my basket also shows customizations. Thus the easiest way would be to work with html. But i'll definately add some kind of unique identifiers, which also to circumwent wrongly replaced lines, if more lines should be identitcal